# The Recursive Song

Tags: wordplay, computer-puzzle, music, cryptic-clues, seasonal

*This is a revival attempt of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-music).*

---

Easter is coming, time to hide some Easter eggs. As you probably know [programmers hide them in program code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29). This type of Easter eggs usually does something completely unrelated to the actual purpose of the affected software. Below you can see the prototype of such an Easter egg in Python, which is supposed to print the lyrics of a song. Of course it shouldn't be too obvious what the code is doing, therefore I used some completely meaningless groups of numbers and letters to represent the structure of the song. Each group would be translated to the actual song text using a dictionary located somewhere else. Unfortunately this dictionary got lost, the one below only includes some examples which don't occur in the song itself. I could of course recreate this dictionary from the song text, if I could only remember which song it was. I need your help to identify it.

```
dict = {
    "TT5134622": "very important",
    "38.9567,-78.8048": "was never made",
    "BEA074B7-1EF6-44B8-80F7-B2F7FF3F6EC0": "it's supposed to be",
}

def decode(s):
    t = " ".join([dict.get(a, a) for a in s.split(" ")])
    print(t[0].upper() + t[1:])

def song(id):
    if id == "subpart1":
        decode("A6DFA780-4D74-4C59-A356-BFE549D32D17 1F6CF 36.2469,-116.8169")
        decode("A6DFA780-4D74-4C59-A356-BFE549D32D17 1F6CF 33.9418,-118.4085")
    elif id == "subpart2":
        decode("47.9529,-91.9714 1-891396-81-1 47.9529,-91.9714 TT0493464")
        decode("TT0446059 34.0555,-118.2498")
        decode("77B3DA14-B08C-445E-9CCF-F795DB7BD11A 1-891396-81-1 77B3DA14-B08C-445E-9CCF-F795DB7BD11A TT0493464")
        decode("2661 79FF6537-4966-4872-AECC-15B58B390C8D 262E")
        song("subpart1")
        decode("A6DFA780-4D74-4C59-A356-BFE549D32D17 1F6CF")
        decode("TT2066951 AED7737E-1DC6-4B90-BBDE-4B924DF0E347")
        decode("2323 1F0CF TT0732174")
        decode("TT2070472 6EB9B81D-B3D6-4BE5-9A5D-BB0CF7B57605")
        decode("-4.0665,37.7485 D44264CA-EEE0-427F-B0D9-8409D47CF36F")
        decode("41.1514,-73.8680 1-4767-8472-8")
        song("subpart1")
    elif id == "part1":
        song("part2")
    elif id == "part2":
        decode("1F426 2208 37.8266,-122.4228")
        decode("1DA39 933E2077-EB50-4EA4-BEA0-1A111AC61B94 23.4359,-109.4265")
        decode("1F333 50.5184,-92.2867 #0000FF")
        decode("2605 51.3809,-2.3595 -90.0000,0.0000 1F341")
        decode("1F4A4 45.1609,-112.9921 2665")
        decode("TT0786245 9CCAAD7C-06FD-4E21-993B-40C5BCE684E0 55.7813,-118.8414")
        decode("45E69B74-BC74-490B-BF8F-54FFBB6FFC4A 42.2817,-89.0952 1F40E")
        decode("0-330-23457-9 1000000000 5E0D2F79-9C17-46B5-BC9B-C061785A485C")
        song("subpart2")
        decode("#191970 2708 7EEBC44F-D79D-4C2D-B4B4-6AA7BDAA16AF")
        decode("51.5060,-0.1324 #FFC0CB 3C0EF08C-A3C9-4E7B-90E2-268E0A51F47B")
        decode("261B TT1136608 TT0120907")
        decode("TT4006594 C0CF3D76-21B5-35AB-959F-97A735E6C79E 1F497")
        song("subpart2")
        song("part3")
    elif id == "part3":
        decode("TT0038011 34.0555,-118.2498")
        decode("TT1509677 6CE89762-8B5E-4A97-AB89-6ECF60D447B2 #1,2,3")
        decode("0-06-061161-8 965E31EF-B9DA-4C1E-BD91-EC89BF7B2F03 #000000")
        decode("#000000 TT0093692 35.5000,-40.8000")
        decode("43.8986,-110.7588 F84C6A70-48E0-3BB1-B01A-07A93D60BFF2 TT4524662 45.4311,-122.3737")
        decode("24.5464,-81.7975 TT0087727 1F6AA")
        decode("0-06-061161-8 0-8129-7869-2 #000000")
        decode("#000000 TT0093692 35.5000,-40.8000")
        song("subpart1")
        song("subpart1")
        song("part4")
    elif id == "part4":
        # TODO: finish this later
        pass

song("part1")
```

> For some reason syntax highlighting is disabled on Puzzling.SE. [This version might be easier to read.](https://repl.it/Byl3/0)
>
> Your answer must contain the song title, the band name and optionally the album title. You don't need to recreate the dictionary, but you must explain why your answer is correct.

**Hints (including the ones from the comments):**

> - I had the idea for this puzzle while watching the blu-ray of a concert which was performed a couple of years ago near a well known village in Germany.
>  - This song was probably never played by a mainstream radio station.
>  - The album where this song is from won a gold award in several European countries.
>  - If the hints don't seem to make sense, try to interpret them differently, use your imagination.
>  - Some say this band would change their female lead vocalist more often than their underwear.
>  - Hints found in the answers below are usually synonyms for words/phrases occurring in the song. In rare cases, where synonyms don't work, they contain a direct reference to the word in question.

Comment: Ok, so you want the name of the song only, right?

Comment: @ABcDexter  Song title, band name, explanation.

Comment: Ok @Sleafar.
Is that dictionary `dict` having right key,value mapping?

Comment: @ABcDexter Yes.

Comment: Reasonably speaking, how well-known is this song?

Comment: @question_asker Most likely you won't hear it played by most radio stations, but the album won a gold award in several european countries.

Comment: So far this has taken me on an odyssey through 1) mostly rap songs and 2) mostly biblically-themed songs

Comment: `23.4359,-109.4265` and others look like latitude and longitude. Maybe the place at those locations contains a hint to what word goes there?

Comment: @Lafexlos To sort out a possible misunderstanding, the "opposite of" part is true **only** for the puzzle intro.

Comment: @Sleafar Yeap, that's why I removed my comment about it. After seeing names of some of them like `stanza 17`.

Comment: Seems to be a song about someone who loves waving at beds.

Comment: Assuming, `part1`, calling `part2` without doing anything means, there is only music(no words/just instrumental) going on over there.

Comment: @BenM That's about as far away from the lyrics as possible using these both hints.

Comment: @Lafexlos Yes..

Comment: When you say "it won't be played by most radio stations", what country are those stations in? (Or does it not matter?)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I don't think its related to a specific country. I've added some hints, hopefully they answer your question.

Comment: @Sleafar is it not played by most radio stations possibly because a lot of things in its genre aren't played by most radio stations?

Comment: @question_asker Direct answer: yes.

Comment: @Sleafar Well then I have an idea about that village...

Comment: @Sleafar - can you clarify your "opposite of" classification? Are you saying the fact that "Meaningless" => "very important" is *not* representative of other similar lookups?

Comment: @Alconja Yes, it was a joke related to the puzzle intro ("completely meaningless groups of numbers and letters").

Comment: @Sleafar - ok, so the content of `dict` as shown is of no value in solving the puzzle (and in fact leads you astray)?

Comment: @Alconja I have added it to show how it's supposed to work, and to hide some small hints/jokes. Apart from that it's not related in any way to the final dictionary.

Comment: @Sleafar - you keep contradicting yourself. :) Does it "show how it's supposed to work" or is it "not related in any way"? I realise the *content* is not related to the final dictionary, I'm talking about the *process* of translating from key to value. Do the actual keys follow the same pattern? I.e. "Meaningless" => "very important" implies that, for example, "Quiet" => "loud"...

Comment: @Alconja I hope the last edit makes this clearer.

Comment: That second-to-last hint (about vocalists) is... not narrowing this down anywhere near as much as I'd hoped.

Comment: @question_asker How about now?

Comment: @Sleafar yoooooooooo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The song is

> [Song of Myself](http://nightwish.com/en/lyrics/imaginaerum/song-of-myself), by Nightwish

The lyrics are as follows ("code" number $\rightarrow$ "codeword" translations courtesy of [Lafexlos's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/29540/17250)):

Bird ElementOf Alcatraz

> *The nightingale is still locked in the cage*

BreathInhale Toxic CaboPulmo

> *The deep breath I took still poisons my lungs*

Tree CoverLake Blue

> *An old oak sheltering me from the blue*

BlackStar TheRomanBaths SouthPole MapleLeaf

> *Sun bathing on its dead frozen leaves*

Sleep Bannack (a ghost town) Heart(Black)

> *A catnap in the ghost town of my heart*

Morpheus TimeforaTale SpiritRiverHighway

> *She dreams of storytime and the river ghosts*

RedLedorDeath (by Mermaid) ElementarySchool Horse

> *Of mermaids, of Whitman’s and the Ride*

TheMysteriousMrQuin ABillion ZapMyWorld

> *Raving harlequins, gigantic toys*

ChantLakeMinnesota TheEgoandtheId ChantLakeMinnesota Wanted

> *A song of me a song in need*

Fearless ConcertHall

> *Of a courageous symphony*

Stanza TheEgoandtheId Stanza Wanted

> *A verse of me a verse in need*

Heart(White) HYMM Peace

> *Of a pure-heart singing me to peace*

AnotherWave (by Heavy Heart) Bed DeathValley

> *All that great heart lying still and slowly dying*

AnotherWave (by Heavy Heart) Bed Angel

> *All that great heart lying still on an angelwing*

OK this is ***very*** long so I'm leaving it here for now; I'll make a few changes to the way the clues were interpreted

**HINTS:**

- *"I had the idea for this puzzle while watching the blu-ray of a concert which was performed a couple of years ago near a well known village in Germany."*
- *"This song was probably never played by a mainstream radio station."*

> Nightwish is a metal band, which is not a genre that gets a lot of airplay. [Wacken Open Air festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacken_Open_Air) is a metal festival that's been held near Wacken, Germany since 1990. Nightwish was one of the headlining bands at the 2013 show, and the Blu-Ray in question is [Showtime, Storytime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showtime,_Storytime).

- The album where this song is from won a gold award in several European countries.
- If the hints don't seem to make sense, try to interpret them differently, use your imagination.

> Possibly (most probably) a reference to the album title, *[Imaginaerum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginaerum)*

- Some say this band would change their female lead vocalist more often than their underwear.

> Nightwish have had [three female lead vocalists over the course of their bandship (pic)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/timeline/6a1d7cc9837f26c98af002085c4d443f.png)

For the sake of completeness,

> *Song of Myself* could be interpreted as "recursive" due to the reflexive pronoun

Comment: Finally. ;) While creating the puzzle I realized that 2 words from the song are enough to google it, therefore I tried to obfuscate it. [Apparently I overshoot the mark a little.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FiFr9mqs_w)

Comment: @Sleafar I am leaving it as-is for the time being - there are a *lot* of lyrics, and I sort of feel like if I clean this up a tiny bit, it should be enough to convince most people it's the right answer (and I'll add stuff about your hints)

Comment: Finally. Good job, really. Now I can be free of my obsession.

Comment: No need to post all the lyrics, it should be clear how the rest woks, after some of the hints are corrected.

Comment: OK, there's the final product (unless I see something else that needs to be changed). Also, I have credited @Lafexlos for his or her hard work on giving us "codeword" translations.

Comment: Bannack is a ghost town, and you should replace RedLedorDeath and AnotherWave by the band name as SlashmanX suggested. The concert I was referring to was on the "Showtime, Storytime" BD from 2013.

Comment: @Sleafar OK - I added bandnames and the ghost town thing in parentheses. Also I don't know how on earth I ended up putting 2014 in there instead of 2013, I was staring right at the year when I typed it.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another non-answer.

After the hints, I am almost sure this is from Wacken 2012 (couple years ago -- in Germany -- not so played genre in radios).

## Colors

```
#0000FF = Blue 
#FFC0CB = Pink
#191970 = Midnight Blue 
#000000 = Black
```

About #1,2,3, counting made much more sense than my previous one. Thanks to @question_asker

## IMDB Links

tt0786245  --  [Morpheus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0786245/)
tt0493464  --  [Wanted](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0493464/)
tt0446059  --  [Fearless (Original Title: Huo yuanjia)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0446059/)
tt2066951  --  [Quiet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2066951/)
tt0732174  --  [The Show Must Not Go On](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0732174/)
tt2070472  --  [What Remains](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2070472/)
tt1136608  --  [District 9](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/)
tt0120907  --  [eXistenZ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120907/)
tt4006594  --  [The Offer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4006594/)
tt0038011  --  [Quiet Please!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038011/)
tt1509677  --  [Pointless](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1509677/)
tt0093692  --  [Over the Top](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093692/)
tt4524662  --  [Stanza 17](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4524662/)
tt0087727  --  [Missing in Action](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087727/)

## Musicbrainz.org Links

bea074b7-1ef6-44b8-80f7-b2f7ff3f6ec0 - [Ambiguous](https://musicbrainz.org/release/bea074b7-1ef6-44b8-80f7-b2f7ff3f6ec0)
A6DFA780-4D74-4C59-A356-BFE549D32D17 - [Another Wave](https://musicbrainz.org/release/A6DFA780-4D74-4C59-A356-BFE549D32D17)
77B3DA14-B08C-445E-9CCF-F795DB7BD11A - [Stanza](https://musicbrainz.org/release/77B3DA14-B08C-445E-9CCF-F795DB7BD11A)
79FF6537-4966-4872-AECC-15B58B390C8D - [HYMM](https://musicbrainz.org/release/79FF6537-4966-4872-AECC-15B58B390C8D)
AED7737E-1DC6-4B90-BBDE-4B924DF0E347 - [Planescape: Torment](https://musicbrainz.org/release/AED7737E-1DC6-4B90-BBDE-4B924DF0E347)
6EB9B81D-B3D6-4BE5-9A5D-BB0CF7B57605 - [...Baby One More Time](https://musicbrainz.org/release/6EB9B81D-B3D6-4BE5-9A5D-BB0CF7B57605)
D44264CA-EEE0-427F-B0D9-8409D47CF36F - [Sonic Reducer](https://musicbrainz.org/release/D44264CA-EEE0-427F-B0D9-8409D47CF36F)
933E2077-EB50-4EA4-BEA0-1A111AC61B94 - [Toxic](https://musicbrainz.org/release/933E2077-EB50-4EA4-BEA0-1A111AC61B94)
9CCAAD7C-06FD-4E21-993B-40C5BCE684E0 - [Time for a Tale](https://musicbrainz.org/release/9CCAAD7C-06FD-4E21-993B-40C5BCE684E0)
45E69B74-BC74-490B-BF8F-54FFBB6FFC4A - [Red Led or Death](https://musicbrainz.org/release/45E69B74-BC74-490B-BF8F-54FFBB6FFC4A)
5E0D2F79-9C17-46B5-BC9B-C061785A485C - [Zap My World](https://musicbrainz.org/release/5E0D2F79-9C17-46B5-BC9B-C061785A485C)
7EEBC44F-D79D-4C2D-B4B4-6AA7BDAA16AF - [Don't Cry to Me Argentina](https://musicbrainz.org/release/7EEBC44F-D79D-4C2D-B4B4-6AA7BDAA16AF)
3C0EF08C-A3C9-4E7B-90E2-268E0A51F47B - [Next To Me](https://musicbrainz.org/release/3C0EF08C-A3C9-4E7B-90E2-268E0A51F47B)
C0CF3D76-21B5-35AB-959F-97A735E6C79E - [All](https://musicbrainz.org/release/C0CF3D76-21B5-35AB-959F-97A735E6C79E)
6CE89762-8B5E-4A97-AB89-6ECF60D447B2 - [Work](https://musicbrainz.org/release/6CE89762-8B5E-4A97-AB89-6ECF60D447B2)
965E31EF-B9DA-4C1E-BD91-EC89BF7B2F03 - [Heavens](https://musicbrainz.org/release/965E31EF-B9DA-4C1E-BD91-EC89BF7B2F03)
F84C6A70-48E0-3BB1-B01A-07A93D60BFF2 - [The Tubes](https://musicbrainz.org/release/F84C6A70-48E0-3BB1-B01A-07A93D60BFF2)

## ISBN of Books

1-891396-81-1 - [Sigmund Freud, The Ego and the Id](http://www.eurobuch.com/buch/isbn/9781891396816.html)
1-4767-8472-8 - [Pico Iyer, Art of Stillness](http://www.lehmanns.de/shop/sachbuch-ratgeber/29826703-9781476784724-art-of-stillness)
0-330-23457-9 - [Agatha Christie, The Mysterious Mr Quin](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/agatha-christie/mysterious-mr-quin.htm)
0-06-061161-8 - [Frederick Buechner, Now And Then](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/frederick-buechner/now-and-then.htm)
0-8129-7869-2 - [Lisa See, The Interior: A Red Princess Mystery (Red Princess Mysteries)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0812978692)

The plain numbers or numbers with letters up to F are unicode characters. U+*CODEHERE*. Thanks to @BenM

**1F6CF** -- Bed emoji,
**1F0CF** -- Joker emoji etc.

As suggested by @agnesi in comments, I directly replaced word with clues. This is the output.

> Bird ElementOf Alcatraz
> BreathInhale Toxic CaboPulmo
> Tree CoverLake Blue
> BlackStar TheRomanBaths SouthPole MapleLeaf
> Sleep HangmansGrasshopper Heart(Black)
> Morpheus TimeforaTale SpiritRiverHighway
> RedLedorDeath ElementarySchool Horse
> TheMysteriousMrQuin ABillion ZapMyWorld
>
> ChantLakeMinnesota TheEgoandtheId ChantLakeMinnesota Wanted
> Fearless ConcertHall
> Stanza TheEgoandtheId Stanza Wanted
> Heart(White) HYMM Peace
>
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel
>
> AnotherWave Bed
> Quiet Planescape:Torment
> Smile Joker TheShowMustNotGoOn
> WhatRemains BabyOneMoreTime
> SameTanzania SonicReducer
> SingSing ArtofStillness
>
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel
>
> MidnightBlue Airplane Don'tCrytoMeArgentina
> TheRoyalSociety Pink NexTToMe
> RightPointingIndex District9 eXistenZ
> TheOffer All Heart
>
> ChantLakeMinnesota TheEgoandtheId ChantLakeMinnesota Wanted
> Fearless ConcertHall
> Stanza TheEgoandtheId Stanza Wanted
> Heart(White) HYMM Peace
>
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel
>
> AnotherWave Bed
> Quiet Planescape:Torment
> Smile Joker TheShowMustNotGoOn
> WhatRemains BabyOneMoreTime
> SameTanzania SonicReducer
> SingSing ArtofStillness
>
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel
>
> QuietPlease! ConcertHall
> Pointless Work Counting
> NowAndThen Heavens Black
> Black OvertheTop AtlanticOcean
> EaglesRestPeak TheTubes Stanza17 HighwayBoring
> SouthernmostPoint MissinginAction Door
> NowAndThen ARedPrincessMystery Black
> Black OvertheTop AtlanticOcean
>
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel
> AnotherWave Bed DeathValley
> AnotherWave Bed Angel

If you want to tweak around, [this repl.it link](https://repl.it/Bz2y) contains, `lyrics.txt`, `clues.txt` and code to convert. (And yes, code is sloppy and can use a lot of improvements but I don't think that's necessary for now.)

Comment: Yep, I think those things are unicode characters. You can look them up at http://unicode-table.com/en/. I suspect the plain numbers (e.g. 2605) are unicode characters too, but you need to search for them with a 'U+' in front of them (e.g. 'U+2605').

Comment: The only keys I'm unsure of now are '#1,2,3' (you gave a couple of explanations but I still think we're missing something) and '1000000000'. Oh, and there's also the little problem that I have no idea how to map those keys to values.

Comment: Dict.get(k,d) tries to look for a key in dict. If the key k is in dict, returns it's value if not returns d. So maybe we should take "100.." as is like "a billion".

Comment: if you replace the values in the example dict, I think you get a clue...maybe we should take the keys at face value?

Comment: Re: #1,2,3 and #010203 - I feel like these could easily be just "counting" within the lyrics

Comment: @agnesi It's worth a shot. Even if we don't get anything, we might see something (like "Hey, these two fit well together!")

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that in the sample dict, the value for the IMDB title "Meaningless" is "very important" which could suggest that we essentially need the 'opposite' of all these clues

Comment: @SlashmanX I said/assumed something like that at first but then saw title like `Stanza 17` and OP also commented about it.

Comment: @Lafexlos Ah right, I had seen that comment by OP but not the one which led to that reply.

Comment: Haha looks like you came to the same conclusion I did about the village/genre

Comment: @question_asker :D the problem is, I have almost no clue about metal so this is as far as I can go. I am just hoping someone else will answer this. lol

Comment: @Lafexlos Yeah, there's still a lot of narrowing-down to do, and even with what I *do* know of metal, it's not like the lyrics are the thing I'm paying good attention to .

Comment: Could the 'Another Wave' clue actually be 'Heavy Heart' (name of the band). Possibly easier to fit into a song. I'm guessing a lot of clues have to be 'worked on' themselves before fitting in

Comment: @SlashmanX Yeap, that's why I added txt files and code. For people to work on as they wish on clues.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the code capitalizes the first word/phrase of each line...

Answer (score 7):

Another non-answer, but will hopefully help someone.

ASCIIThenANSI mentioned in the comments that several keys look like coordinates. I looked up all the coordinate-looking keys in Google Maps, and it appears that this is indeed the case. Some of them point to locations whose names contain simple words, and others are famous buildings/landmarks.

The sample coordinate entry in the dictionary ("38.9567,-78.8048": "was never made") points to **Lost River, West Virginia, USA**.

Here are the other coordinates, in the order that they appear in the code (which, of course, isn't the order they appear in the final song):

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| subpart1           |                                                                                                                        |
| 36.2469,-116.8169  | Death Valley, California, USA                                                                                          |
| 33.9418,-118.4085  | Los Angeles International Airport, Los Angeles, California, USA                                                        |
|                    |                                                                                                                        |
| subpart2           |                                                                                                                        |
| 47.9529,-91.9714   | Chant Lake, Minnesota, USA                                                                                             |
| 47.9529,-91.9714   | Chant Lake, Minnesota, USA                                                                                             |
| 34.0555,-118.2498  | Walt Disney Concert Hall, Los Angeles, California, USA                                                                 |
| -4.0665,37.7485    | Same, Tanzania                                                                                                         |
| 41.1514,-73.8680   | Sing Sing Correctional Facility, Ossining, New York, USA                                                               |
|                    |                                                                                                                        |
| part2              |                                                                                                                        |
| 37.8266,-122.4228  | Alcatraz, San Francisco, California, USA                                                                               |
| 23.4359,-109.4265  | Cabo Pulmo, Baja California Sur, Mexico                                                                                |
| 50.5184,-92.2867   | Cover Lake, Ontario, Canada                                                                                            |
| 51.3809,-2.3595    | The Roman Baths, Bath, UK                                                                                              |
| -90.0000,0.0000    | South Pole, Antarctica                                                                                                 |
| 45.1609,-112.9921  | Bannack State Park (near Hangmans Gulch and Grasshopper Creek), Beaver Country, Montana, USA                           |
| 55.7813,-118.8414  | Spirit River Highway, Spirit River, Alberta, Canada                                                                    |
| 42.2817,-89.0952   | Whitman St (near Wells Park and Haskell Elementary School), Rockford, Illinois, USA                                    |
| 51.5060,-0.1324    | The Royal Society, London, UK                                                                                          |
|                    |                                                                                                                        |
| part3              |                                                                                                                        |
| 34.0555,-118.2498  | Walt Disney Concert Hall, Los Angeles, California, USA                                                                 |
| 35.5000,-40.8000   | Somewhere in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean (the nearest land is Azores, Portugal, but that's still pretty far away) |
| 43.8986,-110.7588  | Eagles Rest Peak, Teton County, Wyoming, USA                                                                           |
| 45.4311,-122.3737  | Clackamas-Boring Highway, Boring, Oregon, USA                                                  |
| 24.5464,-81.7975   | Southernmost Point (southernmost spot in continental USA), Key West, Florida, USA                                      |
| 35.5000,-40.8000   | Somewhere in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean                                                                          |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is interested, there are 78 unique words in this song. The song is sung in the following pattern.  Note: If a word is only used once, then it is represented as a '-'.  If it is repeated, then it has a letter variable.

```
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 A B A C 
 D E 
 F B F C 
 G H I 
 J K L 
 J K M 
 J K 
 N O 
 P Q R 
 S T 
 U V 
 W X 
 J K L 
 J K M 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 - - - 
 A B A C 
 D E 
 F B F C 
 G H I 
 J K L 
 J K M 
 J K 
 N O 
 P Q R 
 S T 
 U V 
 W X 
 J K L 
 J K M 
 - E 
 - - - 
 a - b 
 b c d 
 - - - - 
 - - - 
 a - b 
 b c d 
 J K L 
 J K M 
 J K L 
 J K M
```

There are 28 words that are used multiple times, and 50 words that are used only once.

I do not listen to European songs, so I doubt I will get it from this. Hopefully this is useful to someone else.

Comment: It's worth noting that each of these "words" is probably "phrases", as sampled in the OP's dictionary.

Comment: Judging by what I see here, the song appears to be in the standard "verse, verse, chorus, verse, chorus, verse, out-tro" format.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Perhaps they are phrases, but if you look at the word count of some common songs, (Rhianna, Hopeless place only has 209 words) it is possible that these are in fact words.  This song would have 153 words if they were words instead of phrases.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I notice `J K L / J K M` is repeated quite a bit. My guess is that that part fades out at the end.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Also, the dictionary keys don't actually appear in the song. So I would say each key is supposed to be a word.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI As for the fading - I agree.  As for the key<->word, I think it's up in the air.  The OP gave us sample entries from the dictionary, and EVERY sample is a phrase, rather than a word.  It's not definitive, but pattern leads me to believe the original dictionary worked the same.  That's not to say that some phrases couldn't be 1-word long, of course.

Comment: Re: "European" - you probably have heard some songs from the UK, and even if you've never heard any song by any band from anywhere else in Europe (extremely unlikely), bands from outside Europe also win awards in Europe

Comment: @question_asker I proabably have heard some European songs, but OP said "Most likely you won't hear it played by most radio stations".  I barely listen to music on the radio at all, so if it hardly played, then I have an even lower chance of hearing it.

Comment: @Trenin Fair enough - I guess I'm basing this all on my assumption that someone making a song based on lyrics would probably pick something that people are likely to have heard.